# Баланс-фактор AVL-дерева

Tags: структуры-данных

Как вычислить баланс-фактор C (C: C*h_{min} >= h_{max})?

Он равен √2, но откуда это берется -- неясно.

Comment: Корень из 2 берется, надо думать, из каких-то входных величин, разве нет?

Comment: @Bulson: вот, например, почему баланс-фактор для RB-дерева -- это 2, мне  понятно (там надо рассмотреть самый плохой случай, когда один из путей полностью чёрный, а в другом чередуются красные и черные узлы). Но как в AVL оказался √2 , ума не приложу.